# Does the Protein Data Bank contain the estimated distances obtained using NMR spectroscopy?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb

From the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank) on the Protein Data Bank (PDB) (emphasis mine):

> Most structures are determined by X-ray diffraction, but about 10% of structures are determined by protein NMR. When using X-ray diffraction, approximations of the coordinates of the atoms of the protein are obtained, **whereas using NMR, the distance between pairs of atoms of the protein is estimated**. The final conformation of the protein is obtained from NMR by solving a distance geometry problem.

I am currently working on an algorithm to solve distance geometry problems in the context of molecular conformations. I would prefer to test this algorithm on real data, so does the PDB contain information about the distances between pairs of atoms that were estimated from NMR spectroscopy measurements?

I checked the PDB file for the [2KB7](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/2KB7) protein, but I only found the xyz coordinates of the atoms obtained *after* solving the distance geometry problem. Is it possible to get access to the estimated distances that were used to generate these conformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data can be found here:

https://bmrb.io/search/instant.php?term=2KB7

There is no link directly in the PBD as it is a one-to-many relationship.
Clicking on the first value (a shifts dataset) you get somewhere in the middle a link to the actual dataset, which is a CIF like file with the following table:

```
                              vvvvvvv     
    1 . 1 1  2  2 MET HA H  1   4.070 . . 1 . . . A  2 MET HA . 18256 1 
    2 . 1 1  2  2 MET C  C 13 176.670 . . 1 . . . A  2 MET C  . 18256 1 
                              ^^^^^^^
```

Each row has the spectral shift in ppm (chevrons added) of an *assigned* hydrogen or carbon atom. There are also anisotropic chemical shifts and dipolar couplings datasets etc. etc. Each with a particular piece of data...

Chemical structures are "elucidated" (=solved) in different ways depending on the type of experiment.

Say you wanted only the distanced calculated by [Nuclear Overhauser effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Overhauser_effect) (r_NOE), you would need to find a NOE NMR experiment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm relatively new to the NMR literature. How are spectral/chemical shifts related to the distances between pairs of atoms in a protein?

Comment: Like the solutions to the phase problem in crystallography, the elucidation of the distances depends on the method used and differs between methods. However, the r_NOE mentioned above is a common technique. The elucidation of structures from a simple chemical shifts is not possible in a simple way without a myriad hacks.